# jqGrid page return null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

i have problem with jqGrid and dynamical data binding. 
The problem is, that I allways get Null for parameter page. I am working with MVC3 and jqGrid 4.4.1.

```
 var dataToSend = {
            mrpId: selPRid,
            mrpFilter: cookMainFilter,
            divId: randomId,
            chartId: chartId
        };

        $("#gridMeasurementsTableView" + randomId).jqGrid({
            url: '/DataMonitor/CreateMeasurementTableView/',
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'POST',
            postData: $.toDictionary(dataToSend),
            jsonReader : {
                root: "rows",
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",  
                repeatitems: false,
                cell: "cell",
                id: "id" 
               },  
            colNames: ['Date', 'Value'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Timestamp', index: 'Timestamp', width: 280, 
                    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                            return new Date(parseInt(cellvalue.substr(6, cellvalue.length - 8), 10));
                        }  
                },
                { name: 'Value', index: 'Value', width: 200, align: 'center' }  
            ],
            loadui: "disable",
            loadtext: "Loading",
            viewrecords: true,
            height: "100%",
            caption: "Measurements2",
            pager: $("#gridpager" + randomId),
            rowNum: 10,
            sortname: 'Value',
            sortorder: "asc",
            rowList: [10, 50, 100]
        });
```

and function for getting data is define like this:

```
 public ActionResult CreateMeasurementTableView(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, int mrpId, FilterMRPParameters mrpFilter, string divId, string chartId)
```

br,
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `postData: $.toDictionary(dataToSend)` to `postData: dataToSend`.